# Link to a library directory in Files in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-experience, files, urlhacking, hyperlink, custom-url

I am doing a Lightning remediation for a client moving over from Classic. They have a home page component that has a link pointing to a library directory in Files, not a specific File, but just a directory under Libraries. How does one obtain this URL and link to it in Lightning? I've googled around and have found just about everything EXCEPT what I am looking for. Any ideas? Please and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**ContentWorkspace**

> Represents a content library. This object is available in versions
>   17.0 and later. Use this object to query libraries to find out where documents can be published.
>
> Supported Calls:- create(), delete(), describeSObjects(), query(),
>   retrieve(), update()

Use Name or DeveloperName field of ContentWorkspace to get the id the library and then use this url:- **/lightning/r/ContentWorkspace/recordId/view**

Or simply go to Classic and open the Library which you want to refer in the link and get the id from Url and again use the same URL format stated above. i.e **/lightning/r/ContentWorkspace/recordId/view**

Read more here:- [ContentWorkspace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentworkspace.htm)